# How do you save an entire folder from Google Chrome's Developer Tools' Sources tab?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In Google Chrome's Developer Tools' Sources tabs there is a left side panel which has three tabs with the first one being Sources. Is there a way to download a folder with multiple files and nested folders from this interface? You can right click individual files and 'Save as...' but this is cumbersome.

Comment: This would be a really nice feature to have, thanks to the unfortunate trend of loading lots of sources not referenced in the response text.

Comment: Not supported, but at least there's a [feature request](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=675894) at the Chrome bug tracker that you can star and comment on.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Currently not possible.

> "Saving whole folders is not currently supported."

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/devtools-docs/issues/30#issuecomment-76999063

Here is the corresponding issue in the Chromium Bug Tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=675894

Comment: Have you found any workaround though? Share, please.

Answer (score 305):

It's not possible to do this directly with Chrome, so I made a batching extension to automatically fetch resources to the Downloads folder. You can have a try.

https://github.com/up209d/ResourcesSaverExt

Comment: I cannot see the resource tab where is it? I looked everywhere

Comment: Found it, had to restart chrome/

Comment: Normally, I think it will only need to restart the inspector, not entire Chrome (if it is already opened at the installing time), I should add a note to the instruction later on. Thank you.

Comment: It would be much appreciated if you update the extension, so it can download prettified code. For example, if source maps are available ( webpack:// in Resources ) one can download prettified code and modules

Comment: Done! The feature is now on my Github Repo, though that I think it is easy to do by few Gulp coding lines.

Comment: This extension is gold!

Comment: Looks like the extension is not available in the webstore anymore, you can still install the extension by going to `chrome://extensions/` and using `Load unpacked` to load the `unpacked` folder from the GitHub repo.

Comment: This extension is brilliant! Saving me a ton of time... Thanks!

Comment: This extension is still available. It worked great and was easy to use. Had to restart browser, load webpage, then open dev tools and there is a new tab named "ResourcesSaver". I also starred the Chromium feature request: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=675894

Comment: Does it work, if website built with ReactJS/VueJS ?

Comment: Just an observation but this tool doesn't download any folders coloured orange in the sources file tree. Does anyone know of a tool that does?

Comment: @JackDewhurst those folders represent the virtual filesystem inside a bundled source. I just tried the extension on some bundled files and it did successfully extract the entire original set of files in the correct directory struture, but it put the top directory in an unexpected place within the archive. Maybe try a search for the filenames within the zip.

Comment: Man! Thanks to you I have exported my lost TypeScript code from Chrome.

Comment: this works on linux ?

Comment: This worked great, next question is how do I generate package.json from existing node_modules?

Answer (score 15):

You can look at my CLI tool, webdumper: https://github.com/EllyMandliel/WebDumper

Installation and usage:

```
npm i -g @yokra/webdumper
webdumper -u https://website.com/ -o /path/to/output/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a very useful tool for this, mostly because I couldn't exactly use the answers I found online. A bit of digging and this Chrome extension stands out. I t grabbed everything I needed, as long as it's available in the sources tab.

Save All Resources: https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/save-all-resources/abpdnfjocnmdomablahdcfnoggeeiedb

After successfully installing the extension, restart your browser and navigate to Devtools >> ResourcesSaver to access the extension. Don't try to go through the extensions tab like me. Waste of time * winks *

[image: Save All Resources]