# Is there a way to save the source folder as it is from Chrome's dev tool

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

[image]

As shown in Dev tool in this page, is there a way to save content/js and  questions folder?

Comment: You can at least save each file one by one, by right clicking on each and "Save as..."

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/20710504/5109168

Comment: Yes, we can save files one by one but is there any way to save the entire folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you save an entire folder from Google Chrome's Developer Tools' Sources tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710504/how-do-you-save-an-entire-folder-from-google-chromes-developer-tools-sources-t)