# Is it possible to download the whole folder in Chrome DEV sources

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I need the whole files in a folder, so I hope download the folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported. This question was answered here in the past: [How do you save an entire folder from Google Chrome's Developer Tools' Sources tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710504/how-do-you-save-an-entire-folder-from-google-chromes-developer-tools-sources-t)