# Multiple URLs copy in Sources/Network tab

Tags: google-chrome, url, resources, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to extract multiple resources' URLs in Sources or Network tab of Chrome Dev Tools?
When I want to get URL of a **single** resource, I can do it with context menu function *Copy link address*

[image]

I can switch to this resource from Network to Sources tab and vice versa, but what if I have a need to get URLs of **multiple** resources at once? It is very cumbersome to copy them manually if resultset consists of 200-300 resources.

What I've tried so far:

1. To copy the whole folder from a sources tab, but from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710504/how-do-you-save-an-entire-folder-from-google-chromes-developer-tools-sources-t#comment69592549_20710504) I found out it is not possible for now.
2. To use `$(selector)` as specified in the [Console reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference), in a form of

   ```
   $('img')
   ```

   in case we need to fetch image URLs.

   The complexity of this approach is that it's often hard to distinguish target images on a page that has hundreds of them, and furthermore, multiple versions of the same image (views, previews, small-sized icons and etc.) I.e. **to match** the element inside the tag with the needed resource is not that easy, as it seems. Also not all the file types have dedicated tags (as in the case with `img`).

Maybe I should use `src` tag with some modifiers? Any other suggestions?

Comment: did you try 'copy all as HAR' and then storing the result as a variable in the console then running some simple code like ```copy(a.log.entries.map(e => e.request.url).join('\n'))``` ?

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78118648) to [Chrome Dev Tools: How to copy all URL's from Network Tab at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61256795)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

0. make sure `Network` panel is active
1. switch devtools `Dock side` in the menu to a detached (floating) window

[image]

Next time you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to toggle docking.

---

2. in the now detached devtools press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> on MacOS,
   which will open **devtools-on-devtools** in a new window

---

3. Run the following code in this new window:

   `copy(UI.panels.network.networkLogView.dataGrid.rootNode().flatNodes.map(n => n.request().url()).join('\n'))`

   It'll copy the URLs of all requests that match current filter to clipboard.

---

Hint: save the code as a [Snippet](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/snippets) and run it in devtools-on-devtools window via the commands palette, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> then type the snippet's name.

**In old Chrome the code was different:**

- `copy(UI.panels.network._networkLogView._dataGrid._rootNode._flatNodes.map(n => n._request._url).join('\n'))`
- `copy(UI.panels.network.networkLogView.dataGrid.rootNode().flatNodes.map(n => n.request().urlInternal).join('\n'))`

Comment: Excellent! That's exactly what I want.

Comment: I added the variant with `_flatNodes` to your answer, as only displayed nodes are not very useful. When we have 200+ requests they surely cannot be places within single screen area and one should run this snippet N times moving scroll to the next portion, however `_flatNodes` do it all.

Comment: @Pacerier, No, it's a "hack". I've just examined the [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/) and the actual values in devtools-for-devtools.

Comment: @wOxxOm, You mean there's no tutorial page at all and you just found out there's a devtools for devtools all by yourself?

Comment: The devtools-for-devtools invocation spell itself was mentioned somewhere.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Btw is there a way to get the actual HTTP response body using script? I'd only see `_responseHeaderValues` , 
`_responseHeaders`, 
`_responseHeadersText`, 
`_responseReceivedTime`.

Comment: As per the source code, it's `Promise.all(UI.panels.network._networkLogView._dataGrid._rootNode._flatNodes.map(node => node._request.contentData().then(data => data.content))).then(console.log)`

Comment: Note, copypasting from comments includes nonprintable characters.

Comment: on one computer - the accepted answer works, on another - it fails, both seem to be running up to date chrome. 'ReferenceError - UI is not defined'. any idea why?

Comment: @Joe, sounds like you didn't invoke devtools-for-devtools.

Comment: yes, I did do Ctrl-Shift-i, but wondered whether it did the right thing. is there a way to make sure I am running devtools-for-devtools? the console looks similar in both cases. I wondered it's some extension I failed to install on one pc but not the other...?

Comment: The exact sequence is described in this answer. In the end you'll have two devtools windows.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, I got it working, having two devtools windows was what I was missing.

Comment: In Chrome on OSX, the keyboard shortcut to open devtools-for-devtools is Cmd-Option-i (Cmd-Alt-i)

Comment: It used to work but now I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_dataGrid')   at <anonymous>:1:40"

Comment: For me in the latest chrome I had to do it like this: `copy(UI.panels.network.networkLogView.dataGrid.rootNode().flatNodes.map(n => n.request().url()).join('\n'))`

Comment: It was useful for me to filter out data urls also:

copy(UI.panels.network.networkLogView.dataGrid.rootNode().flatNodes.map(n => n.request().url()).filter(url => !url.startsWith('data:')).join('\n'))

Comment: here is the one that worked for me:
`UI.panels.network.networkLogView.dataGrid.rootNode().children.map(n => n.request().url()).join('\n')`

Answer (score 2):

I found the above method too clunky, its way easier to use fiddler:

- open fiddler (possibly install it)
- filter on the domain name that you are interested in
- clear the screen
- refresh the web page
- Select the fiddler output
- right click and select copy just the URL's

Answer (score 1):

Based on @wOxxOm and @onassar. This worked for March 2023.

```js
window.nodes = UI.panels.network.networkLogView.dataGrid.rootNode().flatNodes;
window.urls = [];
window.nodes.forEach(function() {
    let req_ = arguments[0].request();
    if (req_ !== undefined /*&& req_.statusCode === 404*/) {
        window.urls.push(req_.url());
    }
});
copy(urls.join('\n'));  //copy to clipboard
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Based on @wOxxOm, this worked for me:

```js
var nodes = UI.panels.network._networkLogView._dataGrid._rootNode._flatNodes,
    urls = [];
nodes.forEach(function() {
    var req = arguments[0]._request;
    if (req !== undefined) {
        urls.push(req.url());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A selection and simple copy (Ctrl+C) work for me.
I select URLs in the Url column by the mouse.
Then I use the context menu to copy the list to the clipboard.
The clipboard contents then I can paste to Excel and get the URL list. It adds some empty lines though.

Comment: Works only for visible urls when selecting in multipage list. Ctrl+A solves this but adds garbage to selection