# When does "Start profiling and reload page" decide to stop the automatic recording?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing, devtools

I use the Performance Timeline in Chrome DevTools quite a lot to capture performance recordings of my page.

Most of the time I use the "Start profiling and reload page", which automatically starts and stops the recording.

The question is: **When does DevTools decide to stop the recording**?

I've noticed that it always continues to record at least a few hundred ms past the "Load"-event and tries to figure out when the page has gone "mostly idle".

But that's quite a fuzzy guess. I'd love to know if it relies on some performance event (like the one used in "time to interactive" in Lighthouse)?

Comment: Yep, [3 seconds after `load` event](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/devtools/front_end/timeline/TimelinePanel.js?l=760-770&rcl=326963de).

Comment: @wOxxOm: Wow, impressive that you even included a code reference! Post that as an answer and I'll mark it as correct!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Chrome devtools waits for 5 seconds after `load` event ([source](https://source.chromium.org/search?q=millisecondsToRecordAfterLoadEvent)) since Chrome 85. This is not documented so it may change without notice and did change in Chrome 85 from 3 seconds.

You can modify this behavior in your current debugging session:

1. switch devtools to `Performance` panel/tab
2. open [**devtools-on-devtools**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41202159) and run the following code in its console:

```js
UI.panels.timeline.millisecondsToRecordAfterLoadEvent = 9001.
```

Comment: You really are _the_ Chrome DevTools wizard! Thanks for finding this 

Comment: You can modify devtools code in your current debugging session by running the following code in [devtools-on-devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41202159): `UI.panels.timeline._millisecondsToRecordAfterLoadEvent = 9001` (the main devtools should have Timeline panel active).

Comment: thanks for this answer -- after several Google searches I was finally able to locate it. Is there any way to change this value short of compiling from source?

Comment: @wOxxOm I forgot specifics and this was useful again months later. I should add you to my christmas card list

Comment: @wOxxOm this is really helpful!  checked latest chrome version 109, looks like the default value changed to 5000, and the variable name changed to UI.panels.timeline.millisecondsToRecordAfterLoadEvent

Comment: Confirming that @fankai is right, use `UI.panels.timeline.millisecondsToRecordAfterLoadEvent = 10000` (no underscore prefix anymore)