# Programmatically start the performance profiling in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing

Is there a way to **start the performance profiling programmatically in Chrome**?

I want to run a performance test of my web app several times to get a better estimate of the FPS but manually starting the performance profiling in Chrome is tricky because I'd have to manually align the frame models. (I am using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48081289/981933) to extract the frames)

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> reloads the page and immediately starts the profiling, which alleviates the alignment problem but it only runs for 3 seconds as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54278500/981933). So this doesn't work.

Ideally, I'd like to click on a button to start my test script and also starts the profiling. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in case you're still interested, or someone else may find it helpful, there's an easy way to achieve this using [Puppeteer's tracing class](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.1.1&show=api-class-tracing).
Puppeteer uses [Chrome DevTools Protocol's Tracing Domain](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Tracing) under the hood, and writes a JSON file to your system that can be loaded in the dev tools performance panel.
To get a profile trace of your page's loading time you can implement the following:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  // launch puppeteer browser in headful mode
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    devtools: true
  });

  // start a page instance in the browser
  page = await browser.newPage();

  // start the profiling, with a path to the out file and screenshots collected
  await page.tracing.start({
    path: `tests/logs/trace-${new Date().getTime()}.json`,
    screenshots: true
  });

  // go to the page
  await page.goto('http://localhost:8080');

  // wait for as long as you want
  await page.waitFor(4000);

  // or you can wait for an element to appear with:
  // await page.waitForSelector('some-css-selector');

  // stop the tracing
  await page.tracing.stop();

  // close the browser
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Of course, you'll have to install Puppeteer first (`npm i puppeteer`). If you don't want to use Puppeteer you can interact with Chrome DevTools Protocol's API directly (see link above). I didn't investigate that option very much since Puppeteer delivers a high level and easy to use API over CDP's API. You can also interact directly with CDP via [Puppeteer's CDPSession](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.1.1&show=api-class-cdpsession) API.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: This looks great! Thanks a lot for sharing the snippet.

Comment: Wow -- this is amazing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the chrome devtools protocol and use any driver library from here https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/awesome-chrome-devtools#protocol-driver-libraries to programmatically create a profile.

Use this method - https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Profiler#method-start to start a profile.

Comment: How do I use this from within the code itself ?
i.e. start profiler at point A then stop at point B