# Chrome Dev Tools: How to copy all URL's from Network Tab at once?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way to copy all the loaded links from the Network Tab in Chrome Dev Tools?

Below is the image for example and I want to copy all the files links? How can I do that at once.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple URLs copy in Sources/Network tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200450/multiple-urls-copy-in-sources-network-tab)

Comment: How can I run that code you mentioned in that question? I run in console but it shows an error.  VM216:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: _networkLogView is not defined. Can you please explain how to run that code to copy all links? Thanks

Comment: I've updated the instruction in that answer, see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the '***Save all as HAR with content***' command from the contextual *('right-click')* menu in the *Network* tab of Chrome/Edge/etc. *Developer Tools* to save it as a [`.har`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAR_(file_format)) file. *(For the following example, I named that new file `requests.json`.)*
2. Run one of the following from the directory where you saved that file, replacing `requests.json` with the filename you used when saving that `.har` file *(note: these were tested in the `bash` shell)*:

   a. View the results:

   - `cat requests.json | jq ".log.entries" | jq --raw-output "[.[] | .request.url] | sort | unique | .[]" | less`

   b. Save the results to a text file:

   - `cat requests.json | jq ".log.entries" | jq --raw-output "[.[] | .request.url] | sort | unique | .[]" >> sorted-urls-from-requests_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M).txt`
3. Delete the file you saved in step 1 when have no more use for it. *(it may contain personal information and API keys; depending on the site, it also may be quite large)*

--

*(Source: my [reply](https://gist.github.com/cvan/03ffa0c71317cb6b0b95a41ab189b097?permalink_comment_id=4974163) to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/cvan/03ffa0c71317cb6b0b95a41ab189b097) on GitHub)*