# How can I programmatically get the same headers as "Copy as Fetch (node.js)" from the dev console?

Tags: fetch, google-chrome-devtools, request-headers

I've got a script that automates downloading some a number of files from a webpage. I need to log into the page, so the download request requires things like secure cookies and other headers.

I've created a bookmarklet to quickly grab the ID's I need and paste them into my script, but I also need to go to the network tab, right click a request, `copy` / `Copy as Fetch (node.js)` and then pull out the 2 lines I need and feed them into the script - is there any way to streamline this step?

To be clear, this is not violating any ToS or anything, it just saves me having to make 100+ clicks to download 100+ reports on the poorly created interface.

Comment: You can use devtools-on-devtools for automation, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41202159).

Comment: That's a helpful trick, didn't realize devtools-on-devtools was an option. Unfortunately it's more steps than just grabbing the info manually, and I need to specifically run the `Copy as Fetch (node.js)` tool that appears in the context menu.

Comment: There's probably a way to call that command but you'll need to investigate it by inspecting devtools in devtools-on-devtools :-)